# yii2 getting data from two models and presenting it in view

Tags: yii2

I have two models users and pictures
To draw all pictures in view I have to get string from pictures, one of data is userID, then get string from users according to that userID, so I get userFolder
Then I can draw picture using combined data.

And this must be done for all pictures in DB.

I can start from controller

```
$picturesModel= Pictures::find()->all();
```

But then I have to do what? run a loop while which get users data, and then get complete data for drawing a picture and store it in some new array which after loop finish I should pass to view?  Is this the best way ? or there is anything simple ?

Comment: Use relation. Picture model has relation with User model

Comment: show your Pictures and Users Models

Comment: please show any link on relation example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your Pictures has a relation one to one with Users 
the you can  add to you Pictures model  a function

```
class Pictures extends ActiveRecord
{
    // ...

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Users::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }
}
```

then  if you controller or in your view you need accessing to the user related to the picture you can

```
$pictureModel = Pictures::find()->where(['id'=>123])->one();
```

You can access to the user related

```
$userModel= $pictureModel->User;
```

or for a collection of pictures

```
$picturesModels= Pictures::find()->all();

$userModel = $picturesModels[0]->user
```

or for the loop

```
$picturesModels= Pictures::find()->all();

foreach( $picturesModels as $key => $value ) {

  echo $value->user->your_att;  
}
```

you can take a look at  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html  and  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data

Comment: Looks good but I want to draw all pictures. 
Thus I have to find all from Pictures, then use loop in view file probably. Can u write such example where I could get users data while looping pictures data in view ?

Comment: thanks but one more question. maybe the same.
In controller I must get all pictures
But Loop must be done in the view probably drawing this pictures while looping. So inside that loop I will need corresponding user data.
So how can I do it ?

Comment: Yes you can do this  ..in some cases you need to display information through a loop, especially when there are no available suitable widget .. A view run the php code exactly as the controller (as long as you have access to the necessary classes) ..., if you pass the $picturesModels in render params  this is available in the view

Comment: When I'm looping echo $value->User->userFolder;

I get error 

Relation names are case sensitive. app\models\Picture has a relation named "user" instead of "User".

Relation names are case sensitive. ' . get_class($model) . " has a relation named \"$realName\" instead of \"$name\"."

But in model I gave 
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'userID']);
    }

Comment: I mean I have getUser relation Capital letter for User. and error says that I use small. strange thing :(

Comment: @David   if you have getUser()  you must use user .. this is based on Yii2 naming  convention ..   i have update the answer .. (i'm sorry for the mistake)

Comment: echo $value->user->userFolder;
gives me > Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Are you sure the column name is userFolder and not user_folder ? ... eventually try also $value->user['your_att'];